# How reliable is diff?

Tags: diff, checksum, data-integrity

I copied a large directory from one volume to another (using `rsync`) and subsequently wanted to check whether the copy was indeed correct to verify the integrity of the data. To avoid the lengthy file comparison with `diff` I wrote a little script comparing the SHA sum of every file from the original location and the destination location. I then compared the two and wrote those that differed to another script file to be copied again. I opted for SHA sum because I didn't need to care where the copied files differ, just *that* they differ.

After running the script I was a bit stunned about the enormous number of supposedly different files. So I looked at a few samples out of that set and compared them, but found no differences in either content or metadata. By the looks of it, there are different checksums being produced for identical files in the original location and the destination. This is despite the code generating the checksums across both locations being the same. I have no idea why this fails and produces different SHA sums for identical files.

So I reverted back to `diff` and did a `diff -r orig_dir dest_dir` across the original and destination location. That also produced a list of supposedly different files. Again, when I spot checked a few of these files I found no differences.

I then reverted to run the `diff` over a smaller subset of the locations and voilà, no differences found. I'm now running the command sub-directory by sub-directory and, while a lengthy operation, so far found no mismatches.

If it helps and to provide an idea of the size I'm looking at, one of the largest directories looks like this. The sub-sets I ran `diff` across (and which produced no list of differences) were the directories 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. So comparing ~5,500 files at a time seems to work well, but comparing 88,000+ doesn't:

```
dir1 ; 88,163 files, 849.15 GB
 |
 +-- 0 ; 5,482 files, 45.42 GB
 +-- 1 ; 5,493 files, 48.14 GB
 +-- 2 ; 5,485 files, 49.54 GB
 +-- 3 ; 5,633 files, 50.54 GB
 +-- 4 ; 5,387 files, 47.82 GB
 +-- 5 ; 5,408 files, 42.77 GB
 +-- 6 ; 5,508 files, 49.36 GB
 +-- 7 ; 5,469 files, 55.51 GB
 +-- 8 ; 5,592 files, 51.52 GB
 +-- 9 ; 5,472 files, 50.93 GB
 +-- A ; 5,507 files, 99.18 GB
 +-- B ; 5,618 files, 55.74 GB
 +-- C ; 5,503 files, 47.87 GB
 +-- D ; 5,537 files, 52.63 GB
 +-- E ; 5,582 files, 53.62 GB
 +-- F ; 5,487 files, 48.56 GB
```

Some particulars that might be important:

- System is macOS 13.3.1 (a) (latest revision as of writing this
- arm64 CPU (Apple M1 Max running on a Mac Studio)
- Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0
- Original volume file system is HFS+ (connected via USB-3); destination volume file system is APFS (connected via Firewire 800)
- The only used `diff` command was literally just `diff -r orig_dir dest_dir` with `orig_dir` and `dest_dir` first being across the whole directory tree and otherwise individual sub-directories, one after the other
- Example directory with 88,163 files and 849.15 GB is the largest one; specifically it is the directory structure of the originals directory of the Photos app. A similar directory within (resource/renders/) has 21,700 files and is 27.25 GB, and compared in one go without reporting any differences
- The files, which `diff` and `shasum` reported not to be identical, were different files, ie. the files that `shasum` reported as being different were not the same as those `diff` reported
- The two lines in my script, in which I build the shasums and write them to the external file (as well as stdout) are below. `$1` and `$2` obviously being `orig_dir` and `dest_dir`; `$sha_file_list1` and `$sha_file_list2` are variables holding the names of the shasums and their corresponding file with its full path.

```
echo "starting: find files and their SHA sums in $1"
find "$1" -type f -exec shasum {} \; | sort -k 2 | tee "$sha_file_list1" | pv -i 1 -s $(find "$1" -type f | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c) -N "Processing files..."
echo "starting: find files and their SHA sums in $2"
find "$2" -type f -exec shasum {} \; | sort -k 2 | tee "$sha_file_list2" | pv -i 1 -s $(find "$2" -type f | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c) -N "Processing files..."
```

- FWIW, the script comparison with `shasum` over 88k+ files (and 850 GB) took about 21.5 hours to complete. I haven't measured the time it took using `diff`.
- All `diff` and `diff -r` comparisons (so the individual chunks which I compared) completed successfully. **So both directory trees appear to be identical.**

Does `diff` have problems running over large file sets, either by number of files or the file sizes? Or, what could have led to the supposed differences?

Comment: Notably **BOTH** shasum and diff failed to do the job, this indicates that the problem is elsewhere than in those utilities. *Another possible indicator; 5,500 to 88,000 files - passing from below to above 32767 or 65535 files (top signed and/or unsigned 16 bit value)...*

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The OS is macOS 13.3.1 (a) or "Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0". I didn't use much more than `diff -r "/Volumes/Vol1/dir1/dir2/Users/Alex/dir3/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals" "/Volumes/Vol2/Users/Alex/dir4/dir5/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals"`, for instance. When I did the same `diff -r "/Volumes/Vol1/dir1/dir2/Users/Alex/dir3/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals/0" "/Volumes/Vol2/Users/Alex/dir4/dir5/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals/0"` it completed without a hitch. SHA approach was different from `diff`. Vol1 is HFS+, Vol2 is APFS.

Comment: @Hannu I had this suspicion too, and am running another test across another sub-directory containing more than 185k files and almost 46 GB.

Comment: @Hannu The `diff -r` over those more than 185k files (and 46 GB) completed without any reported differences.

Comment: **(1)** When it takes 21 hours , I would suspect that the Original files have got changed , while the copied files are not changed. **(2)** Both `shasum` & `diff` are highly reliable. **(3)** I would suspect the script whether it is comparing same-to-same. **(4)** When you spot checked the differing files which turned to be same , what was the differing output via your script ? **(5)** That output will reveal what was going on & what was compared & why that was differing !